# Normalizr for ReasonML

Tags: normalization, strong-typing, normalizr, reason, bucklescript

I know ReasonML is a new language so tooling will be a bit behind.  But I was wondering if there was a Bucklescript or ReasonML tool that acts as a Normalizr for data for reason-react.  I know I can just make bindings and put them into [Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) directly, but that doesn't feel right because it feels like it partially defeats the purpose of being in a strongly typed language.

I also attempted to create a normalizr by formatting frontend "models" into lists of "fields", but that approach also felt wrong because it required a lot of boiler plate converting my nice clean records into weird formatted list data structures.

Curious if anyone has run into this in a large reasonML or bucklescript application (if they exist).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- [JsonCodec](https://github.com/state-machine-systems/JsonCodec) might be the closest to what you are looking for, though not exactly the same. It let's you create serialization and deserialization functions with less boilerplate code then other libraries. The decoder returns values wrapper in `Result`.
- [bs-json](https://github.com/glennsl/bs-json) for handwritten JSON serialization and deserialization. One warning is that it throws errors instead of returning a `Result` type so you need to manually catch errors. I do not think the compiler will warn you about errors, whereas with a `Result` type it will ask you to match on `Ok` and `Error`.
- [bs-json-keypather](https://github.com/cxa/bs-json-keypather) uses `Result`, but I have not used it before.